# Adding a value to an append field when the source field do not exist, Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a problem with a append query in access and is that it read from a crosstab query and the data is always changing and sometimes a field in the table that the data will be append do not appear on the crosstab because for that particular day there where no data and I need to append a 0 to the field if the source field,crosstab field, do not exist so the query will stop giving me error and instead append a 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us say you have a table that you wish to crosstab for daily data:

```
ID  EventDate   EventValue
1   08/01/2014  10
2   06/01/2014  10
3   03/01/2014  10
4   02/01/2014  10
5   08/01/2014  10
```

And a crosstab:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Table2.EventValue) AS SumOfEventValue
SELECT Table2.ID
FROM Table2
GROUP BY Table2.ID

PIVOT Format([EventDate],"ddd")
```

You will note that Tue is missing, however, if you add an IN statement:

```
In ("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri");
```

Tue will be shown, that is:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Table2.EventValue) AS SumOfEventValue
SELECT Table2.ID
FROM Table2
GROUP BY Table2.ID
PIVOT Format([EventDate],"ddd")  In ("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri");
```

You can use this idea for any fixed data. It also allows you to show the columns in a specific order.

Note that if you omit a column head, the data will not be shown, even if data exists.

[image: crosstab with column heads]